# Material Setup Versioning

Tags: materials, unity

Working together with Unity, where we impoft blend files and overrride Materials, we rely on the materials of a blender file to remain unchanged.

In Blender, it is easy to accidentally implicitly create additional materials - for example importing some part of a mesh, and merging it into another will add a new material.
Consequently even if Designers pay a lot of attention, this will always continue to lead to broken Materials in Unity that developers need to fix manually.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so before I try to convince stakeholders of putting in dev effort:
Is there already any way to make changes that happen to the material setup of a .blend file more visible, or even have some kind of versioning?